# Подключение к созданной базе данных Firebird

Tags: python, firebird

Попытался установить подключение к созданной базе данных через KInterBasDB

```
import kinterbasdb  
con=kinterbasdb.create_database("create database 'test.db' user 'sysdba' password 'pass'")  
conn=kinterbasdb.connect(dsn='Asus:/test.db', user='sysdba', password='pass')
```

Выдало следующую ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "D:/connect.py", line 2, in <module>  
    con=kinterbasdb.create_database("create database 'test.db' user 'sysdba' password 'pass'")  
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kinterbasdb\__init__.py", line 503, in create_database  
    C_con = _k.create_database(*args)  
ProgrammingError: (-902, 'pyob_create_database: \n  Your user name and password are not defined. Ask your database administrator to set up a Firebird login.')
```

Скорее всего дело в пользователе и пароле к Firebird (если это так, то непонятно почему она возникла - ведь пароль и пользователь стандартные, если они другие то возникает вопрос: как их поменять?) Подскажите вообщем как исправить ошибку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

стандартный пароль не masterkey разве?